# For loop doesn't work in R

Tags: r

I have the following code

```
exam.class <- c("FA1", "FA2", "FA3", "FA4", "SA1", "SA2")
for (i in exam.class) {i}
```

Running the above code I get nothing. Seems like the for loop is not executed.

Expected Result as follows

```
FA1
FA2
FA3
FA4
SA1
SA2
```

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Answer (score 3):

```
exam.class <- c("FA1", "FA2", "FA3", "FA4", "SA1", "SA2")
for (i in exam.class) {print(i)}
```

or `message(i)`.

Comment: or cat(i, "\n")